# Import repeating values to a line chart in Java

Tags: java, sql

I had a database which has lots of tablespaces in it. All tablespaces' used and free spaces are backed up daily (everyday at 3:00 am). All backups are stored in a table called `TBS_SIZE`, which has `tbs_name`, `used_space`, `free_space`, `backup_date` columns.

I need to get the values to a line chart in Java like in this [example](http://sotacs.sourceforge.net/components/dynimg/graphwithmap.html). But the problem is, there is values repeating each day. Because all tablespace names are written again for every day. Therefore some of my columns are looping. Let me give an example:

```
system | 50 | 1 | 12/01/2013

tmp    | 43 | 8 | 12/01/2013

users  | 80 | 2 | 12/01/2013

system | 50 | 1 | 13/01/2013

tmp    | 45 | 6 | 13/01/2013

users  | 77 | 5 | 13/01/2013
```

I need a useful idea, or a reference that can help me.

Comment: So what value do you need to show? Total "used_space" across all the "tbs_name" for each day?

Comment: How about a SQL query like this: Try following SQL

`SELECT sum (used_space), backup_date
FROM TBS_SIZE
GROUP BY backup_date`
This will give you total space date-wise. Then you can pull this data in your Java...

Comment: I need to see values daily, not total sizes.

Comment: The above query will show you the total `used_space` values per day basis.. based on your example, for 12th it will show 173 and for 13th it will show 172. Isn't what you want to see?

Comment: Oh, i didn't read your question at first. I need to see values for each tablespaces.

Answer (score 2):

I would checkout [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm):

[image]

This is the example off the website (with some edits):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
         xAxis.setLabel("Month");
        final LineChart<String,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Tablespaces, 2010");

        //query your data here and prepare to insert it into the chart

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("system ");

        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 23));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 14));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 24));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 36));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 22));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 45));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 43));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 17));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 29));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 25));

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("tmp");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 33));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 34));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 25));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 44));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 39));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 16));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 55));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 54));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 48));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 27));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 37));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 29));

        //etc.
        //create a series for each tbs_name


        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);       
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2);//then add all series here!

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Once you extract the data, you want a `XYChart.Series` for each unique `tbs_name`.  For your x-axis, you want to use time.  However, for your y-axis, you want to choose between either `used_space` or `free_space`.

The best way to approach this ([once you've queried all the results](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)), is to organize all the data first.  Once organized, add each unique `tbs_name` and it's data (`backup_date` and `used_space`/`free_space`) as a new Series.  I would recommend the following object to store all data in:

```
Map<KeyType, List<ValueType>>
```

Where `KeyType` is the unique `tbs_name` and `ValueType` is an `Object` you create which contains just the three pieces of data (`backup_date`, `used_space`, `free_space`).  For example:

```
public class ClassName{
    String backup_date, used_space, free_space;
    public ClassName(String backup_date, String used_space, String free_space){
        this.backup_date = backup_date;
        this.used_space = used_space;
        this.free_space = free_space;
    }
    //write rest of the methods
}
```

[Check out `HashMap` here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: +1 for your example but this doesn't solve my problem. Because resulset is read row by row. I need to use at least 3-4 queries.

Comment: That's fine.  Just produce the data first, then organize.  Once organized, you can produce a systematic way to create these Series (via loops and methods).

Answer (score 0):

in the example you linked it makes up it's own data:

```
/*
 * retrieve stock prices out of a randomDB 
 */
private double[] getStockData(String name) {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    double[] data = new double[MINUTES_BACK];
    double start = random.nextDouble() * 1000.0 + 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        start += start * 0.4 * random.nextGaussian();
        if(start < 0)  start = - start;
        data[i] = start;
    }
    return data;
}
```

You just need to find a way of replacing this random algorithm with you're own data, from whatever data source you have.